# Negative effects of using a generic function like this?

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, generic-function

My question here is, what are the negative effects of using a generic function such as this? Calling this function does work, and in a test console  module, it compiles perfectly fine. I do know this is not a strongly typed function, and is %100 bad practice. But it works... perfectly. The purpose of a function like this, would be to handle string input that needs to be inserted in a particular format depending on the type. I also read some other questions on this here on stackoverflow, and suggestions pointed to using (Of T) functions, and variations like that. Why not do it this way? or is there another simple way of accomplishing this without creating a whole nothing class or larger amounts of code. I know this isn't the "elegant" way of handling this either, so if anyone has suggestions, I'm all ears. Thank you! :)

```
Private Function ConvertFieldValueByType(ByVal type As Field_Type, ByVal value As     String)

    If type = Field_Type.FIELD_TYPE_DATE Then

        Dim dt As Date = DirectCast(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(New Date(1990, 5,  6)).ConvertFrom(value), Date)

        Return dt

    ElseIf type = Field_Type.FIELD_TYPE_DATETIME Then

        Dim dt As DateTime = DirectCast(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(New DateTime(1990, 5, 6)).ConvertFrom(value), DateTime)

        Return dt

    ElseIf type = Field_Type.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB Then

        Return value

    ElseIf type = Field_Type.FIELD_TYPE_LIST Then

        Return value

    ElseIf type = Field_Type.FIELD_TYPE_LONG Then

        Return Convert.ToInt64(value)

    ElseIf type = Field_Type.FIELD_TYPE_NUMBER Then

        Return Convert.ToInt32(value)

    ElseIf type = Field_Type.FIELD_TYPE_SHORT Then

        Return Convert.ToInt16(value)

    ElseIf type = Field_Type.FIELD_TYPE_STRING Then

        Return value

    ElseIf type = Field_Type.FIELD_TYPE_TIME Then

        Dim dt As DateTime = DirectCast(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(New DateTime(1990, 5, 6)).ConvertFrom(value), DateTime)

        Return dt

    ElseIf type = Field_Type.FIELD_TYPE_UNKNOWN Then

        Return value

    Else

        Return value

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Once it has 'if else' all over the function, how is it generic??

Comment: seconded: I would avoid the phrase "generic" here - that term has specific meaning, which *isn't this*.

Comment: I would say this suffer from the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object anti pattern

Comment: First, turn on Option Strict and fix any errors that result.  This Function does not have a return type defined.

Comment: Chris Dunaway - I realize the return type is not defined. That is why I called it a generic function. I realize that's not the common use of the term. I usually use Option Strict, but had to disable it for this one. If not disabled, this function would never work due to it's undefined return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sometimes things like that become necessary, *especially* if the final type is not known at compile time (making most other solutions awkward). My main feedback/observation would be: `Field_Type` looks to be an enum, so you could make this tidier and more efficient with a `Switch`. Re naming, I would *probably* call that something related to `...Parse...` since it takes a `String` (perhaps with a matching `...Format...` that does the reverse), and I think some of the returns (especially "blob" and "list") look a bit dubious. But otherwise: it gets the job done.

Minor point: your `GetConverter` code can take a *type* rather than having to init a struct each time; in C# terms, `typeof(DateTime)` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I will give your suggestions a try.